# QApplication exec() creates new thread / process?

Tags: qt

In QApplication if we call exec() then does a new process / thread start?

Answer (score 5):

No, according to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#exec), calling `exec` will:

> Enters the main event loop and waits
> until exit() is called, then returns
> the value that was set to exit()
> (which is 0 if exit() is called via
> quit()).
>
> It is necessary to call this function
> to start event handling. The main
> event loop receives events from the
> window system and dispatches these to
> the application widgets.

Comment: I want to execute qapplication.exec() in a separate thread and some other processing in second thread. If i directly use exec() then my main thread never gets called till i call exit() and it makes no sense as upon exit my exe shall close. can u provide some direction in this

Comment: `QApplication::exec()` must be called from the main thread. If you want to do work on another thread, by all means create a `QThread`. Use signals/slots to communicate between the main thread (UI) and the `QThread`.